# CustomDial widget causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I am trying to implement a custom qt dial widget by using [this](https://thecodeinn.blogspot.com/2015/03/customizing-qdials-in-qt-part-2.html) tutorial. I have set up everything correctly according to the article however I get a segmentation fault when running.

Header :

```cpp
#ifndef CUSTOMDIAL_H
#define CUSTOMDIAL_H

#include <QDial>
#include <QString>
#include <QSharedPointer>

class QColor;
class QRectF;
class QPen;

class CustomDial : public QDial
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString arcColor READ getArcColor WRITE setArcColor)

    Q_PROPERTY(double arcWidth READ getArcWidth WRITE setArcWidth)

public:

    explicit CustomDial(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

    CustomDial(const QString& text,
               QWidget * parent = nullptr,
               int minimum = 0,
               int maximum = 999);
    ~CustomDial();

    void setArcColor(const QString& color);

    QString getArcColor() ;


    void setStartAngle(double angle);

    double getStartAngle() const;


    void setMaximumAngle(double angle);

    double getMaximumAngle() const;


    void setArcWidth(double px);

    double getArcWidth() const;


    void setText(const QString& text);

    QString getText() const;


private slots:

    void updateValue();

private:

    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override;

    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override;

    double maximumAngleSpan_;

    double startAngle_;

    double arcWidth_;

    double angleSpan_;

    QString valueString_;

    QString text_;

    QSharedPointer<QRectF> arcRect_;

    QSharedPointer<QRectF> valueRect_;

    QSharedPointer<QRectF> textRect_;

    QSharedPointer<QColor> arcColor_;

    QSharedPointer<QPen> arcPen_;
};
#endif
```

Constructor and overridden functions:

```cpp
CustomDial::CustomDial(QWidget* parent)
: QDial(parent)
{ }

CustomDial::CustomDial(const QString& text,
                       QWidget* parent,
                       int minimum,
                       int maximum)
: QDial(parent),
  text_(text),
  arcRect_(new QRectF),
  valueRect_(new QRectF),
  textRect_(new QRectF),
  arcColor_(new QColor),
  arcPen_(new QPen)
{
    QDial::setRange(minimum, maximum);

    QDial::setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);

    connect(this, &QDial::valueChanged,
            this, &CustomDial::updateValue);

    setMinimumSize(100,100);

    setMaximumAngle(-360);

    setStartAngle(270);

    updateValue();
}
CustomDial::~CustomDial() = default;


void CustomDial::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    // So that we can use the background color
    // Otherwise the background is transparent
    painter.setBackgroundMode(Qt::OpaqueMode);

    // Smooth out the circle
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    // Use background color
    painter.setBrush(painter.background());

    // Get current pen before resetting so we have
    // access to the color() method which returns the
    // color from the stylesheet
    QPen textPen = painter.pen();

    // No border
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::NoPen));

    // Draw background circle
    painter.drawEllipse(QDial::rect());

    painter.setPen(textPen);

    painter.drawText(*textRect_, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignBottom, text_);

    painter.drawText(*valueRect_, Qt::AlignCenter, valueString_);

    painter.setPen(*arcPen_);

    painter.drawArc(*arcRect_, startAngle_, angleSpan_);

}

void CustomDial::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    QDial::setMinimumSize(event->size());

    double width = QDial::width() - (2 * arcWidth_);

    double height = width / 2;

    *textRect_ = QRectF(arcWidth_, arcWidth_, width, height);

    *valueRect_ = QRectF(arcWidth_, height, width, height);

    *arcRect_ = QRectF(arcWidth_ / 2,
                       arcWidth_ / 2,
                       QDial::width() - arcWidth_,
                       QDial::height() - arcWidth_);
}
QString CustomDial::getArcColor()
{
    return arcColor_->name();
}
```

The segmentation faults occur inside moc_customdial.CPP wherein a static cast from Q_OBJECT to CustomDial. In theory, this should invoke the CustomDial explicit constructor and all the QSharedPointers inside the class should be allocated memory, however, this is not to be the case. Upon using breakpoints in QtCreator, I have noticed that a member function of the class CustomDial is called before the constructor, and this function involves the use of the above mentioned QSharedPointers.

Where it goes wrong :
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that QtDesigner use the CustomDial constructor `explicit CustomDial(QWidget* parent = nullptr);` where the arcColor_ is not initialized (QSharedPointer does not initialize by default) causing segmentation failures.

On the other hand, I see an abuse of the use of QSharedPointer, I don't see the need for QRect, QColor, etc. to be pointers.

The solution is to create a method that initializes the GUI(the `init` method) and is called by both constructors.

***.h**

```cpp
#ifndef CUSTOMDIAL_H
#define CUSTOMDIAL_H

#include <QDial>
#include <QString>
#include <QPen>

class CustomDial : public QDial
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString arcColor READ getArcColor WRITE setArcColor)
    Q_PROPERTY(double arcWidth READ getArcWidth WRITE setArcWidth)
public:
    explicit CustomDial(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    CustomDial(const QString& text,
               int minimum = 0,
               int maximum = 999,
               QWidget * parent = nullptr);
    ~CustomDial();

    void setArcColor(const QString& color);
    QString getArcColor() ;
    void setStartAngle(double angle);
    double getStartAngle() const;
    void setMaximumAngle(double angle);
    double getMaximumAngle() const;
    void setArcWidth(double px);
    double getArcWidth() const;
    void setText(const QString& text);
    QString getText() const;

private slots:
    void updateValue();

protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override;
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override;
private:
    void init(const QString & text, int minimum, int maximum);

    double maximumAngleSpan_;
    double startAngle_;
    double arcWidth_;
    double angleSpan_;
    QString valueString_;
    QString text_;
    QRectF arcRect_;
    QRectF valueRect_;
    QRectF textRect_;
    QColor arcColor_;
    QPen arcPen_;
};
#endif
```

*.cpp

```cpp
#include "customdial.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QResizeEvent>

CustomDial::CustomDial(QWidget* parent)
    : QDial(parent)
{
    init("", 0, 100);
}

CustomDial::CustomDial(const QString& text,
                       int minimum,
                       int maximum,
                       QWidget* parent)
    : QDial(parent)
{
    init(text, minimum, maximum);
}

CustomDial::~CustomDial() = default;

void CustomDial::init(const QString & text, int minimum,
                      int maximum)
{
    text_ = text;
    setRange(minimum, maximum);
    setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    connect(this, &QDial::valueChanged, this, &CustomDial::updateValue);
    setMinimumSize(100,100);
    setMaximumAngle(-360);
    setStartAngle(270);
    updateValue();
}

void CustomDial::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    // So that we can use the background color
    // Otherwise the background is transparent
    painter.setBackgroundMode(Qt::OpaqueMode);

    // Smooth out the circle
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    // Use background color
    painter.setBrush(painter.background());

    // Get current pen before resetting so we have
    // access to the color() method which returns the
    // color from the stylesheet
    QPen textPen = painter.pen();

    // No border
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::NoPen));

    // Draw background circle
    painter.drawEllipse(QDial::rect());
    painter.setPen(textPen);
    painter.drawText(textRect_, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignBottom, text_);
    painter.drawText(valueRect_, Qt::AlignCenter, valueString_);
    painter.setPen(arcPen_);
    painter.drawArc(arcRect_, startAngle_, angleSpan_);
}

void CustomDial::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    setMinimumSize(event->size());
    double width = this->width() - (2 * arcWidth_);
    double height = width / 2;
    textRect_ = QRectF(arcWidth_, arcWidth_, width, height);
    valueRect_ = QRectF(arcWidth_, height, width, height);
    arcRect_ = QRectF(arcWidth_ / 2,
                      arcWidth_ / 2,
                      QDial::width() - arcWidth_,
                      QDial::height() - arcWidth_);
}
void CustomDial::setArcColor(const QString &color)
{
    arcColor_ = QColor(color);
}
QString CustomDial::getArcColor()
{
    return arcColor_.name();
}

void CustomDial::setStartAngle(double angle)
{
    startAngle_ = angle;
}

double CustomDial::getStartAngle() const
{
    return startAngle_;
}

void CustomDial::setMaximumAngle(double angle)
{
    maximumAngleSpan_ = angle;
}

double CustomDial::getMaximumAngle() const
{
    return maximumAngleSpan_;
}

void CustomDial::setArcWidth(double px)
{
    arcWidth_ = px;
}

double CustomDial::getArcWidth() const
{
    return arcWidth_;
}

void CustomDial::setText(const QString &text)
{
    text_ = text;
}

QString CustomDial::getText() const
{
    return text_;
}

void CustomDial::updateValue()
{

}
```

Comment: Great thanks for your input! So I will be careful about the use of pointers and constructors related to promoted classes next time.